# How to wrap overflowing content in a single row using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container `div` with many child `div` having fixed width. I am using `flexbox` to align the child divs in a single row. Below html and css works except that the first and last child are still overflowing the container div. I want the child divs to be wrapped in single row using a horizontal scroll  -

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.child {
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <div class="child"> </div>
</div>
```

Please see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/akashsolanki/pen/PozRbaE) I've created.

Comment: remove `justify-content: center;` from `.container` class.. i think problem will be solve

Comment: Thanks @noor! After removing `justify-content: center;`, the last element is still overflowing. And the number of child divs is dynamic. I want to center align them if the container has only few children.

Comment: You said *I want the child divs to be wrapped in single row using a horizontal scroll*. Isn't your code already doing that?

Comment: Html and css works except that the first and last child are still overflowing the container div. This.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap all children into other tag to display full content without overflow

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gray;
  flex: 1;
}

.child {
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```